# How to lock a google worksheet macro within google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to lock user from editing macro functions on app script.

my question is: How to allow user to use macro on google worksheet with app script, but lock the app script so that they cannot change the macro?

i tried reader function, but the reader could not use the Macro button. edit function, the editor could access the app script. i saw online about "LockService.getScriptLock" does this help?